# Excel - Highlighting Identical Rows

Tags: excel, highlight, matching

So I have an excel sheet with Five columns. One is an item identification, the others are prices for each buyer. Each column gives a price for an item on a row. The prices are mostly identical across all columns, but some columns are missing a price, or the price is slightly different.

What I want to do is highlight those cells in a row that contain the same price.

Any tips or pointers to a similar question would be appreciated.

EDIT: Solved, I highlighted all four columns and used the Duplicate values under conditional formatting.

Comment: Presumably there is a SKU or other item identification. Try conditional formatting using [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

Comment: try (for columns A to D) as conditional formatting `=AND($A1=$B1:$D1)*LEN($A1)`